# Code recognizing first digit in .Value only

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which works except for one issue. 
It recognizes the value in column H and highlights rows that do not contain a number of 40 or greater in column H for that row.
However, the code below is actually looking for the first digit to be 4 or great, highlighting any row that starts with the numbers 1, 2 or the as the first digit in column H. Hence, it is highlighting rows where the column H value is 100.

```
Sub color40()

Sheets("40+").Select

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Worksheets("40+").Cells(i, 8).Value < "40" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.color = RGB(160, 140, 150)

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

"40" is text, 40 is a number.  When you wrap a number in quotes it won't evaluate numbers normally, it evaluates them as strings.  Try this:

```
Sub color40()

Sheets("40+").Select

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Cells(i, 8).Value < 40 Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.color = RGB(160, 140, 150)

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate only 1 digit you can do it using `LEFT` function.

Syntax:

```
LEFT( text, [number_of_characters] )
```

Example:

```
If LEFT(Worksheets("40+").Cells(i, 8).Value, 1) < 4 Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 8)).Interior.color = RGB(160, 140, 150)
End If
```

Remember to change the value that you need to evaluate.